# Estimating area of overlap between polygons in same layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, overlapping-features

I have a series of buffers representing service areas of bike share stations that extend 400 from the station (network distance). The polygons were generated using Network Analyst. Evidently, buffers of stations that are close to each other overlap. My question is how do I calculate the overlap when the polygons are in the same shapefile (they are rows of an attribute table) and not two different layers?

I tried using the tool 'Polygon Neighbos' but it generated an empty table.

Any thoughts about how I could proceed?

[image]

Comment: Did you have a selection when you ran polygon neighbors? Are you able to use python? Are you interested in finding for each polygon how much is exclusive area and how much is inclusive area which could be summarized for the whole table into a group inclusive area? To do this I would use a python script and do some geometry operations but you could probably fumble through it with a union.

Comment: Intersect using single input. Spatially join result 1:M with originals. Summarise (area?) Using original ids as case field. Transfer result to original.

Comment: Could you make a copy of the shapefile and intersect it with itself? In Python, I'd use a geopandas one-liner to do a self-intersection.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the intersected polygons (in the same shapefile) by do the following:

1- Duplicate your shapefile (copy and paste it).

2- Selection >> Select By Location.

3- Choose  (Are crossed by the outline of the source layer feature).

4- You will get the intersected polygons in the original shapefile.

[image]